# ADB in WSL not finding android emulator

Tags: android, adb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Until a few days ago, i used adb inside wsl just fine with android emulator (in windows).  But something happened and my adb in wsl doesnt find the emulator anymore.

Normally, i make this steps to connect my wsl adb with Android Emulator:

1. adb kill-server (in wsl)
2. adb kill-server (in windows)
3. adb devices (in windows)

At this point, if windows have an android emulator active, should be listed in devices list. If i connect and real device, e.g. adb connect [ip]:5037, works fine with wsl adb. So, is something particular with emulator.

**Infos:**

wsl adb version: 1.0.41, 30.0.4-6686687
windows adb version: 1.0.41, 30.0.4-6686687

I've already tried to wipe emulator data in android studio.